# Can I replicate two couchbase buckets into single elastic index?

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to leverage the join field (i.e. parent-child in old days)

I am using couchbase 4.5.1 community edition and elastic server 5.6.7 with plugin 3.0.1

See
https://docs.couchbase.com/elasticsearch-connector/3.0/advanced-settings.html
and
https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-elasticsearch-connector/tree/release/cypress

Looks like the plugin dumps both couchbaseCheckpoint type document and my own type into the same index!

for join field to work, I must create single type index

How can these both be true at the same time?

How can I ask the plugin to dump checkpoint document in different index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be right -- that won't work with version 3 of the plugin.

Version 4 of the Couchbase Elasticsearch Connector **can** replicate two Couchbase buckets into the same Elasticsearch index, since it stores the replication checkpoints in the Couchbase bucket instead of Elasticsearch. But in February 2019 it doesn't support custom routing, which is required for parent/join. It also requires Couchabase Server 5.0 or later.

I'm afraid the official connector doesn't currently provide a good way to do what you want.

Disclaimer: I maintain the Couchbase Elasticsearch Connector.

Comment: this would mean that we can use old style parent child type docs in 5.6.7 and we cannot upgrade out elastic anytime soon

Comment: For more discussion, see [CBES-110](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/CBES-110).